# Сделать "Колесо" или "Барабан"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не знаю как правильно назвать) как можно сделать такую штуку (каждый столбик можно прокручивать отдельно колесом мыши или соотв. пальцем) ?
Похожая штука есть у Яндекса [Демо](https://yandex.ru/design/ony) , но разобраться не смог(
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Там по верстке видно что используется sweper slider

http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/090-vertical.html вот нужный вам пример

http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#mousewheel вот нужный вам параметр для активации скролла с помощью колеса мыши